# Edge loops to multiple faces

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I want to select multiple faces and make 4 horizontal edge loops (Ctrl+R) on them.
How to do that without doing it one by one?

EDIT: When faces are seleced, how to create horizontal loops on them?

Faces are selected. Now I want to add horizontal loops on each on one of the them. How to do that in one go. So, I don't need to do the same action for every face.
[image]

Comment: Documentation on selecting edge loops:
https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#selecting-loops

Comment: I know how to select loops. I want to create loops on multiple selected faces.

Comment: Are you trying to cut new loops into existing faces?

Comment: @Dan Monsic
It might work with the subdivide tool
1 select the edges
2 press 'W'
3 select subdivide

If that doesn't work, include some screenshots so it's easier for the community to see what's wrong

Comment: I think CTRL-R works only on a single edge loop, while he wants it to act say on 3 edge loops, separately, but in the same way, so that if he sets 4 "cuts", each edge loop gets 4 cuts, 12 total. This is different from subdividing though.

Comment: @Delagone , Ctrl+R works only on one face. I want to do that on multiple faces. Subdivision adds both horizontal and vertical loops on the faces, so I can't use it because I want only horizontal ones.

Comment: @DanMonsic In order to have the subdivide option work properly you should only select the edges where needed.
You have selected to much edges. DESELECT the edges located on the Ngons and it should work.
Also it's better to get work in edge select mode instead of face select for this kind of modeling. That's why subdivide won't work.